# First-person or Third-person Question Writing

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

When writing questions should *I* write them in first-person or third-person?

**or**

When writing questions should *one* write them in first-person or third-person?

---

Which of the above to is the best practice for asking questions on Judaism.SE? Or does it make a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My opinion: Either. It doesn't matter; it's a personal-style issue.

But "I" questions of the halachic sort always make me want to say "CYLOR" (and sometimes I do). "One" questions don't quite as much.